# How to show pdf in a modal window using ajax?

Tags: javascript

I want to show the pdf inside the modal window using ajax,
The url I am calling is sending response type as "application/pdf" , when I show the http.responseText into the modal div, it shows some unreadable text.

>>>
endobj
15 0 obj
<>
endobj
16 0 obj
<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageC]/XObject<>>>/Rotate 0/Type/Page>>
endobj
17 0 obj
<>stream
h޴�mo�rǿ�y���|&�I�$��"No�.���M8�a+ͷ��7C��Vd7�r�\�p8�3��a;�z[=�v�R?�-�8��mEtB:�N����:q��ԩ��괦'��u;��/����⻫��~��~~>|~��{����^=�~�������ǯ����y�?zt�ͫ�7�m�w�.����O�ᷙp}������葦�ۛ�Wo��gO�_��������~�~{���Ͼ|�ꧫ�/�������*u���3*�}�E�R�����W7��M__������*n-���W>���7/.~{��W*������mv˶m���7��^����.y����>t��*R��0���_�.����o��|�
?�ysu�엋��z�������y\<��|q��˗?��:lOo�~��aċ~}eS�����Wo.�sn��b[����S����������+��������}��_/__,�^<�Q;��ᑧ��tz� @t���m���v�l�͞����.0�a�v�-b� z��."K;7��6=Z��=�8�G���!��9�����Ɓ�*�6�
z��C��W�X�  (�i��x�Ck~�m�[��U�KaN>�Re4�u���2^f�@8֪�
����&�E�\m�b�н/ދ��D�~�1^r:j=�����I,��fJ�&ę���82�� �
ǃ�a�`�Q�9�{fa�:q{(j����@q���c�SD���{@�f�����) �uHeϥX�d=��;D�&p�������s�9�!zN���KT�aG���T'����� "��1ky�2������І(���W-�^�'b�A廒�i��#���Ў�i?�6\��\��c�sz�:��V�ut��.�$���4����9ݏ���f�B���Dw�Yp����^!�J��&�i���!/�p���*�1�[L�C1�E�[6B�� j�    R�ÑlӯF��(u�l*�0���\��

Comment: The url that you're calling - set that as an `iframe`s `src`, and embed the `iframe` in the modal. Easy one that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display PDF using an AJAX call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559060/display-pdf-using-an-ajax-call)

Comment: "show pdf on web page ajax" google this keyword and then click on first result. Learn to google first.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get text by returning the pdf, you have to have a program that will interpret that data, which is normally the pdf reader plugin that most modern browsers are equipped with.

Use an iframe in your modal:

```
<div class="modal">
    <iframe src="/url-to-pdf"></iframe>
</div>
```

This is a rough example, but you get the idea. If this is embedded in your html, the iframe will be loaded automatically, so you may want to choose when to invoke it via javascript.