# display pdf with the returned data - not iframe - by using ajax call - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559060/display-pdf-using-an-ajax-call) question is not answering my situation as it is not providing a solution, and I am wondering if now (by 2018) we have a better approach.

So the problem is I would like to call my server which is creating pdf file (not physically) and giving the contents of the file as stream to the `http response`. Now, with an ajax call to this web service, I want to display the returned data as a pdf file if possible.

```
function callProducePdf(webServiceUrl, resultAreaId){
        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: webServiceUrl
        });

        jqxhr.done(function(data){
            //data contains the pdf in inputStream form
            //how can I display the pdf in resultAreaId which is a div?             

            //if I do something like this it works but this is not what I want
            var iframe = $('<iframe height="500px">');
            iframe.attr('src', webServiceUrl);
            resultAreaId.prepend(iframe, "<br>");
        });

        jqxhr.fail(function(){
            //I have this function defined which is working fine
            appendError(resultAreaId);
        });
    }
```

server side code:

```
@GetMapping("/producePdfWithDefault")
public ModelAndView producePdfWithDefault(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/path/a/static/pdf/file.pdf");       
    InputStream resourceAsStream;
    try {
        resourceAsStream = resource.getInputStream();
        byte[] resourceInBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(IOUtils.toByteArray(resourceAsStream));
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("content-disposition","inline; filename=documentPreview.pdf");
        response.setContentLength(resourceInBytes.length); 
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        output.write(resourceInBytes);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            response.setStatus(500);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you..

Comment: if return data is byte array. browser will download that data into pdf format.

Comment: I can convert it to byteArray on the server side. let me try it.

Comment: @NegiRox unfortunately after converting the returned data to byte array, it displays the data as it is (byte array)

Comment: no i am talking about your response is it byteArray?

Comment: @NegiRox yea I converted the output to byte array on the server side, so the data I am getting with my ajax request is in byte array form. see the edited section of my question.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this...

```
...
jqxhr.done(function(data) {
  var blob = new Blob([data]);
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = "<ANY_FILENAME_WITH_EXTENSION>";
  link.click();
}),
...
```

*(untested)*

Client will download the file and open it in the default PDF reader.

Comment: thank you for the response, the requirement is to display the pdf on the page. The way my application works is, user starts a test with a given time intervals to see if the server is able to create and return the pdf files. The test keeps running until the user stops it. So as the test is running, after each call I need to display what is returned in the resultArea

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to render your PDF into a `canvas` element.

The demo below is from their [examples](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples)

```js
// atob() is used to convert base64 encoded PDF to binary-like data.
// (See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/
// Base64_encoding_and_decoding.)
var pdfData = atob(
  'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
  'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
  'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
  'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
  'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
  'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
  'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
  'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
  'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
  'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
  'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
  'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
  'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G');

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

// Using DocumentInitParameters object to load binary data.
var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({
  data: pdfData
});
loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
  console.log('PDF loaded');

  // Fetch the first page
  var pageNumber = 1;
  pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
    console.log('Page loaded');

    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.then(function() {
      console.log('Page rendered');
    });
  });
}, function(reason) {
  // PDF loading error
  console.error(reason);
});
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

<h1>PDF.js 'Hello, base64!' example</h1>

<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
```