# using pdf.js with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, pdf.js, phpbb

I run a phpBB board, where I'd like to incorporate pdf.js for pdf presentation (so I can include it in a lightbox; but, I digress).  Attachments in phpBB are retrieved using a id, invoking file.php.

Here's a webpage where I present three thumbnails for a pdf:  http://59plymouth.net/lightbox/pdfjs2.html

If you click on the first thumbnail, it presents a pdf using pdf.js, but without invoking file.php.

If you click on the second thumbnail, it presents a pdf by invoking file.php, but using the native pdf app for presentation (i.e., w/o pdf.js).

If you click on the third thumbnail, it attempts to present the pdf with a combination of file.php and pdf.js:  ...href="./pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=./download/file.php?id=16187

But of course, the second "?" that invokes file.php is treated literally as data, and not as a query.  I've surmised enough to know that I have to use AJAX to accomplish what I want to do, but I don't know how to do it.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559060/display-pdf-using-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

Well, whaddaya know...  This construct works:

http://59plymouth.net/lightbox/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://59plymouth.net/59test/download/file.php%3Fid%3D16187